# Connecting to a Redis available in different aws region

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

Can I connect to a redis available in different aws region? If yes, how would be the write latency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can connect to AWS ElastiCache Redis in different Region. There is nothing stopping you, but you have to follow some standards and architectures to get good latency and security features.

Answer to your second question, yes there will be some latency issues, For more you can refer the below link.

[Accessing an ElastiCache Cluster when it and the Amazon EC2 Instance are in Different Amazon VPCs in Different Regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/elasticache-vpc-accessing.html#elasticache-vpc-accessing-different-vpc-different-region)